# @firebase/database Warning

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, expo

I get the following warning when using Firebase with Expo

[2018-07-09T10:44:16.148Z]  @firebase/database:
- node_modules/expo/src/Expo.js:21:41 in warn
- node_modules/@firebase/logger/dist/index.cjs.js:66:31 in defaultLogHandler
- ... 19 more stack frames from framework internals

```
  _fetchCoDocs = coId => {
    const rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
    const coDocsRef = rootRef.child(`coDocs`);
    coDocsRef
      .orderByChild("companyId")
      .equalTo(coId)
      .once("value", snap => {
        console.log(snap.val());
        console.log(Object.values(snap.val()));
      });
  };
```

Can I just ignore this warning? Will it affect my app in production?

If the warning can be ignored, how do I turn off the warning?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get rid of the warning by adding an .onIndex in my firebase rules

Comment: Could you provide more information on how you managed to fix the issue? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Just saw your message. In my firebase rules, i added an indexOn and it fixed the issue. example as follow.... hope it helps you     "coData": {
          ".read": true,
     ".write": true,
         ".indexOn": "companyId"
       },